# Hibernate bidirectional Many-to-one association error

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have two classes I'm trying to associate, and on runtime I get the following exception:

```
org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: BidProposal.parents in Parent.bidproposals
```

Can anyone find the error here, I'm on it for hours...

The classes look like this:

Parent.Java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "parents")
public class Parent extends User implements java.io.Serializable {
  private Integer id;
  private Set<BidProposal> bidproposals = new HashSet<BidProposal>(0);

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getId() {
    return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
    }

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "parents")
    public Set<BidProposal> getBidproposals() {
    return this.bidproposals;
    }

    public void setBidproposals(Set<BidProposal> bidproposals) {
    this.bidproposals = bidproposals;
    }

}
```

And the BidProposal.Java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "bidproposal")
public class BidProposal implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer id;
    private Parent parent;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getId() {
    return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id", nullable = false)
    public Parent getParent() {
    return this.parent;
    }

    public void setParent(Parent parent) {
    this.parent = parent;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have mappedBy = "parents", but the member in BidProposal is called "parent"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown
>   target entity property: BidProposal.parents in Parent.bidproposals

It means that the property **parents** cannot found in the entity **BidProposal** .

It should be :

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "parent")   
public Set<BidProposal> getBidproposals() {    
   return this.bidproposals;  
}
```

Comment: Jesus christ I'm so noob, I thought that the mappedBy should reference the containing class table name...